# Diferença de horas entre duas datas com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.

Tenho essas duas datas:

```
   var dtPartida = "20170620 11:20";
   var dtChegada = "20170620 16:40";
```

E preciso descobrir a diferença em horas entre essas datas que no caso e 5 horas e 20 minutos.

Preciso que retorne assim:

> **5h 20m**

e não assim:

> **05:20**

Comment: Adicione seu código @Newtech!

Comment: Desculpa! Atualizei a pergunta para ficar mais fácil de entender.

Comment: var dtPartida = 20/06/2017  11:20  ??

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim

Comment: editei a resposta, veja lá

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ficou show. Você sabe se tem como retornar assim: 5h 20m?

Comment: veja lá na resposta

Comment: Afiinal de contas qual o formato da data a ser tratada? pela resposta escolhida acho que ficou duvidas se é 20170620 11:20 ou conforme vc disse no comentario "@LeoCaracciolo Sim – Newtech 7 horas atrás". De qq forma para retornar (5h 20m)  era só retirar os  :  (dois pontos)lá da expressão e dar um espaço  var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m"; editei novamente a resposta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manualmente com javascript, da pra criar um date a partir da string, pegando separadamente ano, mês, dia, minuto e segundo, e depois calcular a diferente entre as datas (e minutos e segundos).

**Exemplo**

```js
var dtPartida = "20170620 11:20";
var dtChegada = "20170620 16:40";

var date1 = new Date(dtPartida.slice(0,4), dtPartida.slice(4,6),dtPartida.slice(6,8), dtPartida.slice(9,11), dtPartida.slice(12,14)),
    date2 = new Date(dtChegada.slice(0,4), dtChegada.slice(4,6),dtChegada.slice(6,8), dtChegada.slice(9,11), dtChegada.slice(12,14));

var diffMs = (date2 - date1);
var diffHrs = Math.floor((diffMs % 86400000) / 3600000);
var diffMins = Math.round(((diffMs % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
var diff = diffHrs + 'h ' + diffMins + 'm';
console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 14):

Uma poderosa biblioteca javascript para manipulação de datas [**Moment.js**](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
  var dtChegada  = "20/06/2017 16:40:00";
  var dtPartida = "20/06/2017 11:20:00";

  var ms = moment(dtChegada,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(dtPartida,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
  var d = moment.duration(ms);
  var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

console.log(s);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> **Para retornar no formato pedido no comentario 5h 20m**
> basta agir na variável   `s`
>
> `var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m";`

```js
  var dtChegada  = "20/06/2017 16:40:00";
  var dtPartida = "20/06/2017 11:20:00";

  var ms = moment(dtChegada,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(dtPartida,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
  var d = moment.duration(ms);
  var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m";

console.log(s);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Supondo os horários que mencionou antes da edição da pergunta:**

```js
var dtChegada  = "16:40";
var dtPartida = "11:20";

var ms = moment(dtChegada,"HH:mm").diff(moment(dtPartida,"HH:mm"));
var d = moment.duration(ms);
var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m";
  
console.log(s);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Para o caso das datas estarem no formato da resposta do Lucas Costa**

```js
  var dtChegada  = "20170620 16:40";
  var dtPartida  = "20170620 11:20";

  var ms = moment(dtChegada,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(dtPartida,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
  var d = moment.duration(ms);
  var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + "h" + moment.utc(ms).format(" mm") +"m";
  
  console.log(s);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gosto Moment.js !

Comment: Essa biblioteca só funciona se tiver data? Ela não trabalha apenas com horas não?

Answer (score 4):

Tu pode testar pelos minutos ou segundos das horas:

```
function verificarDiferencaHorario(inicialMin, finalMin) {
        var totalMin = Number(finalMin - inicialMin);
        console.log(Math.trunc(totalMin / 60).toString() + ":" + (totalMin % 60).toString());
    }
```

Supondo os horários que mencionou:

```
function verificarHorario() {
        var inicial = "11:20", final = "16:40";
        var splInicial = inicial.split(":"), splFinal = final.split(":");

        var inicialMin = (Number(splInicial[0] * 60)) + Number(splInicial[1]);
        var finalMin = (Number(splFinal[0] * 60)) + Number(splFinal[1]);

        verificarDiferencaHorario(inicialMin, finalMin);
    }
```

O mesmo vale para dias: a última conversão em minutos e a função verificarDiferencaHorario retorna em horas e minutos a diferença.