# Diferença de Mês no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação simples que calcula a diferença entre duas datas, no console já consigo fazer a diferença entre os anos mas não consigo calcular a diferença de Mês.

```
var botaoCalcular = document.querySelector("#calcular");
botaoCalcular.addEventListener("click", function (event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = document.querySelector("#calculaPeriodo");

    let data1 = form.dataInicio.value;
    let data2 = form.dataFim.value;

    let dataI = data1;
    let dataII = data2;

    const dataSplit = dataI.split('/');
    const dataSplit2 = dataII.split('/')

    const day = dataSplit[0]; // 30
    const month = dataSplit[1]; // 03
    const year = dataSplit[2]; // 2019

    const day2 = dataSplit2[0]; // 30
    const month2 = dataSplit2[1]; // 03
    const year2 = dataSplit2[2]; // 2019

    dataI = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    dataII = new Date(year2, month2 - 1, day2);

    const diff = Math.abs(dataI.getTime() - dataII.getTime());

    const anos = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));

    const mes = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
    
    console.log(dataI);
    console.log(dataII);
    console.log(diff);
    console.log(anos);
    console.log(mes);

})
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Retornar em horas a diferença entre duas datas em JAVASCRIPT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104969/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Diferença entre datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13046/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Diferença de horas entre duas datas com JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213301/3774)

Comment: Não é em JavaScript mas pode te ajudar (a ideia é a mesma): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/370215/112052

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer a diferença em meses ou anos, não precisa calcular desta maneira.

O problema de meses e anos é que eles não têm tamanhos fixos. Um mês pode ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, e um ano pode ter 365 ou 366 dias. Então pegar a diferença em milissegundos e dividir por algum valor médio arbitrário será sempre impreciso (na maioria dos casos pode não dar problema, mas há *corner cases* demais, conforme já explicado [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/370215/112052)).

Inclusive, na pergunta citada acima há uma alternativa - na minha opinião, melhor - para calcular esta diferença:

```js
function ajustaMesAno(d) {
    return d.getFullYear() * 12 + d.getMonth() + 1;
}

let inicio = new Date(2018, 0, 20); // 20 de janeiro de 2018
let fim = new Date(2020, 9, 10); // 10 de outubro de 2020

let diffMeses = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);

console.log(diffMeses); // 33

// ou, se quiser separar em anos e meses
let anos = Math.floor(diffMeses / 12);
let meses = diffMeses % 12;
console.log(`${anos} anos e ${meses} meses`); // 2 anos e 9 meses
```

O detalhe é que o código acima não leva em conta o dia. Ou seja, a data inicial é 20 de janeiro e a final é 10 de outubro, mas mesmo assim foi considerado o mês de outubro no cálculo. Mas se você só quer que ele seja contado apenas a partir de 20 de outubro, basta ajustar:

```js
function ajustaMesAno(d) {
    return d.getFullYear() * 12 + d.getMonth() + 1;
}

let inicio = new Date(2018, 0, 20); // 20 de janeiro de 2018
let fim = new Date(2020, 9, 10); // 10 de outubro de 2020

let diffMeses = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);
if (inicio.getDate() > fim.getDate()) diffMeses--; // <- ajuste para considerar o dia

console.log(diffMeses); // 32

// ou, se quiser separar em anos e meses
let anos = Math.floor(diffMeses / 12);
let meses = diffMeses % 12;
console.log(`${anos} anos e ${meses} meses`); // 2 anos e 8 meses
```

---

Outra opção é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
let inicio = new Date(2018, 0, 20); // 20 de janeiro de 2018
let fim = new Date(2020, 9, 10); // 10 de outubro de 2020

// obter o total de meses
let diffMeses = moment(fim).diff(moment(inicio), 'months');
console.log(diffMeses); // 32

// ou usando duration
let diff = moment.duration(moment(fim).diff(moment(inicio)));
console.log(`${diff.years()} anos e ${diff.months()} meses`); // 2 anos e 8 meses
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

No caso, [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) já leva em conta o dia (se o início é 20 de janeiro, somente a partir de 20 de outubro a diferença seria de 33 meses).

Answer (score -2):

Seu cálculo de ano e mes está sendo feito da mesma maneira

```
const anos = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
const mes = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
```

O calculo do mês não deveria estar multiplicando por 365 (dias).